# $ \int_{\partial B_2(0)} \frac{3z+1}{z(z-1)(z-3)}dz $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How do i calculate $$\int_{\partial B_2(0)} \frac{3z+1}{z(z-1)(z-3)}dz$$ $   z  \in C$

I have tried partial fraction but i dont get it...

Comment: Is $\partial B_2 (0)$ supposed to indicate circle of radius 2 around 0 oriented counterclockwise?

Comment: yes, sry i forgot to mention

Comment: If you haven't seen residue theorem yet, I think you are supposed to use the formula $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{\mathrm dz}{z-a} = 2 \pi i \mathrm{Ind}_{\gamma} (a)$$ where $\mathrm{Ind}$ denotes the *index* (also known as *winding number*). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{\partial B_2(0)} \frac{3z+1}{z(z-1)(z-3)}dz=2\pi i\bigg[\text{Res}\bigg(\frac{3z+1}{z(z-1)(z-3)},z=0\bigg)+\text{Res}\bigg(\frac{3z+1}{z(z-1)(z-3)},z=1\bigg)\bigg]=2\pi i(\frac13-2)=\frac{10\pi i}{3}.$$